# Finnair power sockets

Tags: air-travel, power, aircraft, finnair

I am flying with Finnair for the first time and I am going to spend 10+ hours in the airplane.

I had asked Finnair, how can I power my laptop on-board. And they replied that I can 'use the power socket' and 'no adaptor is required'. So I am quite confused.

How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finnair generally use a fairly standard "universal" 2/3 prong power socket that will accept (at least) plugs with a US or European style plug, with power at 110 volts.

Depending on the specific plane it may also have the even-more-universal socket that will also take UK, Australian, etc, plugs - however I would not recommend relying on that as not all planes have them.

If your plug is non-US/UK, then you will likely need to use an adapter to connect it.

The "no adapter is required" comment relates to the original in-air power sockets which which required an "adapter" (basically another power pack) in order to use them with most equipment - they are saying that no such adapter is required on their planes.

Comment: Why 110V? Wouldn't 220V be expected as this is Europe?

Comment: 110V is generally safer to interact with than 220V, which is crucial when flying on an airplane.

Comment: Seatguru.com confirms the 110v. http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Finnair/Finnair_Airbus_A330-300.php